# Stored Procedure always returning default value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have written a stored procedure for simple user Login function.

```
USE [project]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[authenticateLogin]    Script Date: 10/18/2013     9:24:57 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[authenticateLogin] @userName varchar, @password varchar
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @userRole int;
    Declare @uPassword varchar;
        Declare @uRole int;

    SET @uPassword = (SELECT uPassword FROM [user] WHERE uName=@userName); 

IF(@uPassword = @password)
    SET @userRole = (SELECT uRole FROM [user] WHERE uName=@userName); 
ELSE
    SET @userRole = 0;
--RETURN @userRole
SELECT @userRole 
END
```

And I am calling this from my program like this:

```
internal int Authenticate(string userName, string password)
    {
        int userRole = 0;
        Shared shrObj=new Shared();
        string encPassword = shrObj.EncryptToString(password);
        SqlConnection sqlCon = Shared.GetSqlCon();

        var sqlCom = new SqlCommand("authenticateLogin", sqlCon);
        sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;           

        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
        sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", encPassword);
        try
        {
            userRole = Shared.ExecuteNonQueryOnProcedure(sqlCon, sqlCom);
            if (userRole > 0) return userRole;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            //catch
        }

        finally
        {
            Shared.COC(sqlCon);
        }
        return userRole;
    }
```

In `Shared.cs`

```
public static int ExecuteNonQueryOnProcedure(SqlConnection sqlCon, SqlCommand sqlCom) {

        int rowCount = 0;
        SqlParameter returnParameter = sqlCom.Parameters.Add("userRole", SqlDbType.Int);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        try
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            //rowCount = sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var inu = sqlCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catch
            return rowCount;
        }
        return (int)returnParameter.Value;
    }
```

But the issue is it always return me 0 even where provided arguments are matched. please help me where am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok Guys, got it working it was a stupid mistake which me or neither anyone else realized.

I was not specifying the characters values in `varchar(?)` hence it was only taking first character of every variable and hence the `if-Else` block was failing. fixed that and everything is fine now.

Thanks everyone for helping out. :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't pass `EXEC procedure` with SqlCommand. Use [CommandType.StoredProcedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype.aspx)

```
var sqlCom = new SqlCommand("authenticateLogin",sqlCon);
sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //here
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", encPassword);

try
{
    userRole = (short)sqlComm.ExecuteScalar();
    if (userRole > 0) return userRole;
}
```

To get Return Value you can add a parameter like:

```
SqlParameter returnParameter = sqlCom.Parameters.Add("userRole", SqlDbType.Int);
returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
sqlCom.ExecuteScalar();
int returnValue = (int) returnParameter.Value;
```

Comment: tried the `returnValue` still contain 0 and `ExecuteNonQuery();` is returning -1

Comment: @Maven, in your SP instead of returning value do `SELECT @userRole` as the last statement, `ExecuteNonQuery` should work.

Comment: still no luck, i have edited the question with my full code, actually i ma using a separate function to make my query and seperate to run it due to some requirements, so probably i am missing some thing there?

Comment: @Maven, modify your stored procedure to `SELECT @userRole` at the end, put a debugger in your C# code and see what you get on `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: already did `SELECT @userRole` thing, and `ExecuteNonQuery ` is returning -1

Comment: @Maven, my bad, call `ExecuteScalar`, not `ExecuteNonQuery`, I don't know how I started talking about `ExectuteNonQuery`, that will give you the number of records affected.

Comment: check my code again plz, now my `inu` variable just get empty string `""`.

Comment: @Maven, are you sure your column `uRole` has some value and not just a null ?

Comment: the problem is in my `if-else` block. because in the second last statement if i am setting `SET @userRole = 1;` thn i get one in the `inu` var. i dont know whats wrong there. can u plz check.

Comment: @Maven, this has to do with the parameter you sending, do you have encrypted password stored in database, and are you using the same encryption in C# ? You should check if the password you are passing has the same value as in the table ? because **definitely**  they are not same. I don't think this problem lies in the current scope of the question. Just make sure you are encrypting the password correctly

Comment: got it working it was the issue in SP, please see my answer below. Thankyou for helping though.

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL you should have

```
SELECT @userRole
```

instead of

```
RETURN @userRole
```

[ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) will execute the command and return value of the first column in the first row that the SQL command produces, not the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return a value from an SP like that, in fact the return value is not much use.

If you want to use an SP for authentication like that then something like the following would work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[authenticateLogin] @userName varchar, @password varchar
AS
BEGIN
SELECT uRole FROM [User] 
WHERE uName=@userName AND uPassword = @password
```

This will return the uRole field for all users with a matching username and password which will hopefully be either 1 or 0 rows.